# How to fix this constant current drive circuit?

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, constant-current

I have selected a constant current source to drive LCD in my design but doesn't work well, so I'd like someone to help me pinout where the problem is.

The LCD backlight requirement is as below.The constant current source chip I use is [CAT4139](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT4139-D.PDF).
[image]

My constant current circuit is like this, LEDA/LEDK are connected with LCD.
[image]

However, the LCD cannot turn bright on PCB. The measured voltage on LEDA is only 8.4v and the voltage on LEDK is 0v.

My question is why this circuit doesn't work? How can I do the calculation in designing stage to avoid this failure based on the information provided by the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT4139-D.PDF)? Is there anything I can do now to make up on the PCB?

---

Edit:

PCB layout
[image]

### L4 is [PA4332](https://products.pulseelex.com/files/product_files/P761.pdf)

Solved:
Thanks to Pintergabor and Jack Creasey's help, this problem is solved after following steps.

1. Changed the L4 into 22uH, the issue was still there.
2. Changed the D5 into another Schottky diode which has reverse voltage 30v and the problem is solved, the LCD can turn bright.

Comment: A casual look says that it should be OK.  Switching supplies can be tricky -- please show us your layout, and give us the manufacturer and part number for L4.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a couple of problems with your design:

1. D5 needs to be a Schottky diode (and as noted in another answer needs to be able to withstand the string voltage). I doubt that D1 is reverse avalanching since you don't report excessive heat, but you should select a more appropriate diode.
2. The chip draws pulses of current up to 750mA, but with L1 being only 10uH you may well be putting the chip into overcurrent shutdown. When this happens the soft start is initiated so it is likely this what is preventing you achieving the right string voltage.

Why did you select an inductor half of the value recommended in the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT4139-D.PDF)? See page 8.
Are you aware that this changes the peak current radically?

Answer (score 2):

Please use a diode with higher voltage ratings.

When the regulator is switching, SW is pulled to GND and then released. C116 charges up to 10V, but in the next cycle D5 reverse breaks down, and activates the overcurrent protection of U23. Soon both D5 and U23 will be very hot and D5 may even die.

If it does not work even after you replaced D5 with a higher voltage one, and U23 too, because it may have been damaged by the misuse, try different capacitors. Some low quality capacitors may not work well at 1MHz switching frequency.

If nothing helps, connect an oscilloscope to SW and show me what you see.